# Carrierwave different permission per uploader for S3 storage?

Tags: permissions, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I would like to specify different permission per uploader when file is uploaded- for example photo attachment is public, while system upload file attachment is private, is that possible to set that as per uploader basis?

Answer (score 5):

Just have to make your uploader class override the base class.  I tore my hair out today too.. :(  This worked for me:

Using Carrierwave 0.8.0
/app/uploaders/whatever_uploader.rb

```
class WhateverUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def fog_public
    true # or false
  end
end
```